# Change button style onclick ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

So i have my Index View in which I have a table which lists me all the data i need, thourgh a foreach loop.
**Here is part of my Index.cshtml**

```
 <table class="table">

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
 
                <td style="vertical-align:middle">
                    <div>
                        <img src="@("~/image/"+item.Poza)" asp-append-version="true" width="135" height="210" align="left" style="margin-right: 15px" />
                    </div>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle">
                    <div>
                        <span style="font-weight:bold">Titlu: </span><span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Titlu)</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span style="font-weight:bold">An: </span><span> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.An)</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span style="font-weight:bold">Durata: </span><span> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Durata)</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span style="font-weight:bold">Nota: </span><span> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nota)</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span style="font-weight:bold">Recenzie: </span><span> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descriere)</span>
                    </div>

                    </p>
                    @if (item.UserId != ViewBag.userid)
                    {<form asp-action="PostLike" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                        <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Like" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </form>}

                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Near the end of the page, i have my Like button. I would like to change its color when is pressed, and change it back again at the next click, so the user knows which films he liked and which he didnt. How could i do this? Becuase if I add a simple javascript function like

```
 function color1() {
      document.getElementById("btn").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
```

it changes only the color of the first button.
I mention that everytime the like button is clicked, the page refreshes. So i need that button color to remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

How are you storing their likes? Need to check that value on page load.

Comment: I am storing the likes in a table "LIKE". Which has Id, LikeNumber, UserId and FilmId. The last two are foreign keys, so I can know which user liked which film. Can you give me a example how to check that value? Hope the explanation helps.

Comment: Not sure on what kind of table.

Comment: But need to grab the current user id, search the table for values where currentID == UserID && FilmId == CurrentFilm

Comment: It's a table named "Like". But how do i do this in a JavaScript function?

Comment: Don't, use c# to grab it and then pass value to js.